# Почему Яндекс.Метрика не видит нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, php, яндекс-метрика

Нужно к кнопке добавить ID, чтобы метрика отслеживала нажатия. Имеется код кнопки:

```
<div>
    <? if ($arResult['PRICES'][$sPriceCode]['CAN_BUY'] == 'Y' && $arResult['CATALOG_AVAILABLE'] == 'Y'): ?>
        <form method="POST" style="margin-right:300px" class="basket-form" data-ajax="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam(); ?>>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ADD2BASKET">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $arResult['ID']; ?>">
            <input type="number" min="1" max="999" value="1" class="quantity" name="quantity">
            <input type="submit" value="<?= $arParams['MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET']; ?>" class="button">
            <input type="hidden" name="basket_url" value="<?= $arParams['BASKET_URL'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price_code" value="<?= $sPriceCode ?>">

          </form>
    <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Код для обработки события:

```
"onclick="yaCounter35993580.reachGoal('ORDER'); return true;"
```

Делал так:

```
<form method="POST" style="margin-right:300px" class="basket-form" data-ajax="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam(); ?>"onclick="yaCounter35993580.reachGoal('ORDER');">
```

Но не при каких условиях метрика нажатия не видит, `return true` добавляю - тоже ничего не меняется. Куда его по правильному нужно всунуть, чтобы все заработало?

Comment: Вы уверены что создали и правильно настроили цель на странице целей? https://metrika.yandex.ru/[YOUR_ID]?tab=goals

Comment: Естественно, цель там есть, идентификатор цели ORDER, все как нужно